# Content Provider | Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri$Builder android.net.Uri.buildUpon()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am implementing Custom Content Provider and the problem is when i insert any value it gives me exception

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri$Builder android.net.Uri.buildUpon()' on a null object reference
```

my code for inserting the value is

```
    public final static Uri uri = "content://com.test.myproject.Models.myProvider/users";
    ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues(0);
    updateValues.put("name","ali");
    updateValues.put("description","basic user");
    updateValues.put("status",0);
    context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, updateValues);`
```

If you need more info/code them lemme know.

 Kindly help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: In which line the error is raised ?

Comment: it was in last line... now resolved thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with the Uri.Builder class ?

```
Builder builder = new Uri.Builder(); 
builder.scheme("content"); 
builder.authority("com.test.myproject.Models.myProvider"); 
builder.appendPath("users"); 

//...

context.getContentResolver().insert(builder.build(), updateValues);
```

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html)